# How to remove/check for anchor tags in a dynamically loaded html in Angular JS 11

Tags: javascript, angular

So I am new to the community (long time SO consumer).  I am working on an kiosk application using Angular JS via a chromium browser (kiosk mode).  The issue I have is that I need to include a privacy and terms of service (ToS) page in several languages which may have unwanted links.  Rather than building components/pages for the various languages all I have is a privacy page that call an api/service and a set of html formatted files for each of the languages (these files will likely come from the marketing/legal teams - and they'll probably pull it from the company website without removing the links).  The api in essence pulls/serves the html/body file for the corresponding language.

Interestingly enough all the other pages will remain in English (US) but the privacy and ToS can not.  Note: The kiosk needs to also work offline (not connected to the internet) but may connect occasionally if possible for updates.  The api and app is delivered internally (using localhost) by a Node-Red app/flow (all part of an IoT solution).

The problem is that when this dynamic html is loaded, if the html contains anchors and the user were to click on one of them then the app will navigate and there is no mouse keyboard to navigate back.  The obvious solution is to not put the links in the first place, but the likelihood is that the marketing folks will copy the privacy **body** or ToS from their main website and hand to us.  There may be 10 to 20 or more links per file and there may be 20 files or so for the languages.

I was hoping to use an Angular JS scheme in TypeScript to look at the dynamically changed DOM and strip out or modify the href attributes of any and all anchor tags essentially "disabling" preventing navigation.  I was avoiding JQuery directly.  I also don't want to touch/modify the html files - may need to strip out inline javascript or script tags too.

I was also looking to see if there was a way to intercept the click event on the anchors and prevent navigation for anything not already defined in the app router.

Lastly, I may look at chromium to prevent navigation to anything other than localhost - but this seems suboptimal.

Any ideas welcome.
In the component .html...

`<div [innerHtml]="htmlData"></div>`

In the component .ts...

`import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

:

`constructor(public http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public restApi: DeviceApiService) { }`

:

`this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.htmlString);`

where **htmlString** contains the response/payload from an API call (based on language) with responseType:text

I've noticed that bypassSecurityTrustHtml is prudent for use to use as the source of the content is known.  It also allows inline CSS to be render appropriately.

a sample html snippet with line breaks and elements within anchor... (you can see this was from an office doc).  It's ugly but valid.

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:6.0pt;margin-left:.5in;background:white'>
            <span style='font-size:9.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:#828282'>
                &nbsp; To learn more about
                cookies, please visit&nbsp;
            </span><a href="http://www.allaboutcookies.org/">
                <span style='font-size:9.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:#0C8CAA'>
            http://www.allaboutcookies.org</span>
            </a><span style='font-size:9.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:#828282'>.</span>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the raw HTML string, your options are limitless. You can use Regular expressions to strip out external links and replace it with whatever you deem is necessary.

If regex is not a viable option you can iterate over the dom and remove the href from the anchor tags.

[Here is a Working Demo on stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdnpya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlData: SafeHtml;
  formattedHtmlData: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let htmlString: string = `<div>Some Text</div> <a href="https://google.com">External Link 2</a>`;

    let formattedHtmlString = this.striplinks(htmlString);
    this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlString);
    this.formattedHtmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      formattedHtmlString
    );
  }

  striplinks(text) {
    var re = /<a\s.*?href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']*?>(.*?)<\/a>/g;
    var str = text;
    var subst = '$2';
    var result = str.replace(re, subst);
    return result;
  }

removeHrefFromAnchorTags(html) { 
var container = document.createElement('p');
container.innerHTML = html;

var elements = container.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0, max = elements.length; i < max; i++) {
  debugger;
  if (elements[i].tagName === 'A') {
    (elements[i] as HTMLAnchorElement).href = '';
  }
}

return [].map.call( elements, function(node){
    return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
}).join("");
```

}
}

Comment: Got to admit it's clever.  My only concern is accounting for variances in allowable syntax like line breaks. (added example to question).  Would it be better to navigate through DOM?

Comment: Updated the example. I agree regex can be a bit tricky to cover all scenarios. However with a good regex, should be able to cover almost all possible combinations.  Since regex is not a 100% fool proof, have added another way of iterating the dom and removing href from the hyperlinks. In the stackblitz, I just managed to extract the text and display but you will have to apply the css classes as well. This will remove all hrefs on anchor tags.

Comment: Was this any help at all?

Comment: Alvin Yes! Thank you and apologies for the delayed response.  I ended up using the removeHrefFromAnchorTags method in my utilities helper service (since there is another component with a similar need).  I made minor modification to: `(elements[i] as HTMLAnchorElement).href = 'javascript:void(0);';`  and on the map call `return node.outerHTML;`  worked like a charm.  I'll eventually extend it to strip out script tags as well.  Thanks!